# IIS Rewrite Module exclude bots but allow GoogleBot

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I'm using the following IIS Rewrite Rule to block as many bots as possible.

```
<rule name="BotBlock" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^$|bot|crawl|spider" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
</rule>
```

This rule blocks all requests with an empty User-Agent string or a User-Agent string that contains `bot`, `crawl` and `spider`. This works great but it also blocks `googlebot`, which I do not want.

So how do I exclude the `googlebot` string from the above pattern so it does hit the site.

I've tried

`^$|!googlebot|bot|crawl|spider`

`^$|(?!googlebot)|bot|crawl|spider`

`^(?!googlebot)$|bot|crawl|spider`

`^$|(!googlebot)|bot|crawl|spider`

But they either block all User-Agents or still do not allow googlebot. Who has a solution and knows a bit about regex?

**So thanks to The fourth bird the solution becomes:**

```
<add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^$|\b(?!.*googlebot.*\b)\w*(?:bot|crawl|spider)\w*" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match bot, but not google bot:

```
^$|(?<!\bgoogle)bot|crawl|spider
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jD7hz8/1)

Or you could group the alternatives in a non capture group and surround that group with word boundaries to prevent partial matches for all alternatives:

```
^$|\b(?:bot|crawl|spider)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8DhxC7/1)

Comment: Thanks. The first regex does work perfectly as a regex, but does not work in the web.config. It's an xml and adding the `<` (escaped to `&lt;` or not) threw a 500.19 error. The second one did work, but it needed to match bot, crawl etc exactly. I made some tweaks and it is closer now https://regex101.com/r/1vO1QH/1. Any ideas to capture `__bot` and `__bot__` as well?

Comment: @VDWWD Like this? `^$|(?:__|\b)(?:bot|crawl|spider)(?:\b|__)` https://regex101.com/r/gFrptq/1

Comment: Sorry, the `__` are just meant to represent random characters before and after, not those underscores specifically... So `xybot`, `xybotxy` etc.

Comment: @VDWWD Then you could use word boundaries and a negative lookahead `^$|\b(?!googlebot\b)\w*(?:bot|crawl|spider)\w*` https://regex101.com/r/UEVr19/1

Comment: Thanks! The last one works perfectly! But i did change it to `^$|\b(?!.*googlebot.*\b)\w*(?:bot|crawl|spider)\w*` so that it can contain googlebot and not be a perferct match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex `^$|(?!.*googlebot)(bot|crawl|spider)`

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this regex may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are . Please [edit✏️] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: This regex does not work, it still triggers on the bot part in googlebot.